# Is Module a binding context for Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I have an application which might needs to connect to multiple databases. But each module will only connect to one db. So I though it might make sense to isolate the db into each module so each module will get its own db auto resolved and I don't need to bother with named registration. But to my astonishment, it seems that Autofac's module is more a code module than a logical module (am I wrong here?): IA

```
[Test]
public void test_module_can_act_as_scope_container()
{
    ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(new Module1());

    IContainer c = builder.Build();
    var o = c.ResolveNamed<CB>("One");
    Assert.That(o.A.Name, Is.EqualTo("One"));

    builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(new Module1());
    builder.RegisterModule(new Module2());
    c = builder.Build();
    var t = c.ResolveNamed<CB>("One");
    Assert.That(t.A.Name, Is.EqualTo("Two"));
}
```

And the interfaces/Modules used:

```
public interface IA
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CA : IA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CB
{
    public CB(IA a)
    {
        A = a;
    }
    public IA A { get; private set; }
}

public class Module1 : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c => new CA() { Name = "One" }).As<IA>();
        builder.RegisterType<CB>().Named("One", typeof(CB));
    }
}

public class Module2 : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c => new CA() { Name = "Two" }).As<IA>();
        builder.RegisterType<CB>().Named("Two", typeof(CB));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're kind of correct.

Modules serve only for splitting configuration into somewhat independent parts. They do not scope configuration in any way. Having modules is actually the same as if you merged all modules' `Load` methods' code into a single configuration method and then built the container.

In your case your `Module2` actually overrides the registration for `IA` interface from `Module1`.

I've also been interested in finding a solution to the problem. I've come to the following approach:

**Keyed service**

```
var key = new object();
builder.Register(c => new CA() { Name = "Two" }).Keyed<IA>(key);
builder.RegisterType<CB>().Named("Two", typeof(CB))
  .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
      (pi, ctx) => pi.Type == typeof(IA),
      (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveKeyed<IA>(key)
  ));
```

Pros:

You can control which `IA` instances will be injected in each module.

Contras:

1. It's quite a lot of code
2. It does not make `IA` component 'internal' to the module - other modules can still resolve it using simple `Resolve<IA>`. Modules aren't isolated.

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

In some cases it may be easier, and frankly more correct from design point of view, to make it this way:

**Delegate registration**

```
builder.Register(ctx => new CB(new CA { Name = "Two" }))
  .Named("Two", typeof(CB));
```

Pros:

1. You don't expose your module-specific `CA` to other modules

Contras:

1. If `CA` and `CB` have complex dependencies and a lot of constructor parameters, you'll end up with mess of constructing code
2. If you need to use `CA` in several places inside a module, you'll have to find a way to avoid copy-pasting

**Nested Container instances**

And yet another option is having an independent `Container` inside each module. This way all modules will be able to have their private container configurations. However, AFAIK, Autofac doesn't provide any built-in means to somehow link several `Container` instances. Although I suppose implementing this should not be very difficult.

Comment: Accepted.

The post before update was exactly what I wanted to avoid. I have thought about also the updated one, but wondered if there is a better solution. Seems no other way until Autofac can support a hierarchical module.
Peter's solution does work, but it is too hacky..

Answer (score 1):

You could use nestet lifetime scopes. These form a hierarchy in which subscopes can resolve services registered in superscopes. Additionally, you can register unique services in each subscope, like this:

```
var cb = new ContainerBuilder();
cb.RegisterModule<CommonModule>();
var master = cb.Build();

var subscope1 = master.BeginLifetimeScope(cb2 => cb2.RegisterModule<Module1>());
var subscope2 = master.BeginLifetimeScope(cb2 => cb2.RegisterModule<Module2>());
```

With this setup, services in `Module1` will only be available to instances resolved from `subscope1`.

Comment: This really works, in my case, as long as I mark the registered components as singleton, then they won't be released once the life time scope is disposed. But it's too hacky from my point of view. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I agree, this approach can be used in some cases. But lifetime scopes are designed for different purposes. And this way cannot resolve one quite common use case: exposing `CB` component to the root scope while providing it with internal components from a nested module scope. The only way to achieve this would be `Updating` the root container after beginning nested scopes... and I can't tell whether this would work at all.

Comment: Well... you could keep that scope as long as the application runs - wouldnt that be the same as having nested child configuration?